# Is it possible that only one user can checkout an object on powerbuilder?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, powerbuilder

I have a project and i want to have more control with the changes.
For example:

Tom have w_principal with checkout
Scott need to make changes to the w_principal file.

I want you not to be able to checkout before tom checkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article ([Checking objects out from source control](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00844.1252/html/pbug/BABDJDCH.htm)), by default when you check out an object in PowerBuilder, it will locks the object in the archive so that no one else can modify it—unless your source control system permits multiple user checkouts

For TFVC, in Visual Studio we can set the lock type to prevent others check-out if using the server workspace.

So, you can check if there's the context options/ways in PowerBuilder to set the lock types against the server workspace.  If no such options, then I'm afraid it's not supported.

BTW, you can take a look at below articles for “best practices” suggestions for using PowerBuilder in source control:

- [PowerBuilder and TFS Source Control](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/dave/archive/2011/02/07/powerbuilder-and-tfs-source-control.aspx)
- [PowerBuilder: Article - Source Code Control](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/42500)

[image]

Comment: @MarcoMireles Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Answer (score -1):

More than one user shouldn't be able to check out an object at a time.  You just need to put your project into Source Control.  The built-in Source Control in PB should give you everything you need.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. TFVC supports checking out files without locking them. Exclusive locks can be configured but can only be enforced via the user of server workspaces.

Comment: Native PB source control should only be used with very small, trivial projects.